# OpenCart - htaccess don't work - no redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I have this htaccess, but the 301 redirect don't work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to redirect a basic url, but it doesn't work, I get a "404 page not found"-Message.

I tested the following, but nothing worked.

```
Redirect 301 ^test123$ http://www.domain.com/shop/notebook-reparatur/acer
Redirect 301 /test123 http://www.domain.com/shop/notebook-reparatur/acer
RewriteRule ^test123.*$ http://www.domain.com/shop/notebook-reparatur/acer/ [R]
```

Can anyone help me in my basic problem, I don't undestand why it doesn't work..

thanks, regards
recep779

Comment: Did you enable mod rewrite in apache?

Comment: Do you have your app as virtual host? If yes please post your httpd-vhosts.conf and apache version as well.

Comment: no, i don't think that it is virtual host.. all things was installed normally (upload on webspace etc...). i can't get my apache version.. have tried it with php info but their is nothing else as "Apache", no version.

I have bought an extension plugin to redirect urls, that is not working too..